# Libgdx gui TextArea, how set number of lines to enclose multiline text String?

Tags: fonts, libgdx, width, textarea, lines

TextArea seem to require me to set a fixed number of lines to show my text on. However, how can I know how many lines I should set, when my TextArea width is sized differently on different types of phones? A sensible TextArea component would incorporate a function that can automatically set the number of lines required due to the number of characters, the width of the TextArea and the size of the font used.

In short: How can I know the number of lines for my fixed-size String?

Comment: If you know the approx. length of one line, then you can divide your string length by that number and you'll get number of lines.

Comment: Thx, but seems a lot of hassle. Is there no better way, really?

Comment: Maybe, you can use a Table? I think I saw some useful line-wrapping methods there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Label](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html) object. From the docs:

> A text label, with optional word wrapping.

Which sounds like what you need. Note that `Label` is part of the [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) framework.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for actually.